# Recently Played section of Apple's Podcast app not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, podcasts

I recently switched back to Apple's iOS podcast app, and it looks like the Recently Played ("Nylig spilt" in norwegian) section is not behaving properly. I can't make sense of which podcasts/episodes appears in this list, or in which order they are sorted.

Only some old podcasts appear here, and there is no logic to which one. The HighExistence podcast I have never started listeing to yet, and the other podcasts listed is really old, and not played using Apple's podcast app. I listened to these using Pocket Casts, but don't think this app can pick this up.

[image]

Also when I tap on "Show all" the list is not sorted at all. Not sorted after date or anything, just scrambled around.

[image]

I tried to delete the app and data, and install it back in again, without it working, except the HighExistence podcast was added, without me having listened to it yet.

So, anyone know the expected behaviour of this section, and maybe have a solution? I would guess it would show the podcasts I recently finished in sorted order, which would be useful.